# invalid 'in' operand obj JQUERY - Type Error while trying to fetch data from JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, jsp

I have a jsp page which tries to pull data from the backend and populate it inside a drop down box, however i keep getting this "invalid 'in' operand obj" error.

My code is

```
$.get('../Paid_deep_dive',{type:"bodyload",s_date:$start_date,e_date:$end_date},function(responseTM) { 

                var $select = $('#tm'); 
                $select.find('option').remove();

                $.each(responseTM, function(key, value) {  

                $('<option>').val(key).text(value).appendTo($select); 

                });


});
```

and my servlet code goes something like this

```
  if(type.equals("bodyload"))
{
    try
    {

      prepStmt = con.prepareStatement(dbquery.get_trademark);
      rs=prepStmt.executeQuery();
      while(rs.next())
        {
        json.put(rs.getString(1),rs.getString(2));
        System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
        System.out.println(rs.getString(2));
        }


    String responsetojsp=json.toString(); 
    System.out.println(responsetojsp);
    response.setContentType("application/json");
    response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    response.getWriter().write(responsetojsp);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
          logger.error("Error : " + e);
    }
}
```

And when i output my JSON the output is like this

> {"11":"Trademark 2","6":"Trademark 1"}

And my jsp code for the same is as follows

```
<div id="filter-panel" class="collapse filter-panel">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <b><font color="#545454" size="2px">START DATE</font></b>
                        <b><font color="#545454" size="2px">END DATE</font></b>
                        <input type="text" id="datepicker1" onchange="loadpage()">-
                        <input type="text" id="datepicker2" onchange="loadpage()">       
                        <label class="filter-col" style="margin-right:0;" for="pref-orderby">Trademark</label>
                        <select id="tm">
                            <option value="trademarks">Trademark 1</option>
                        </select>
                        <label class="filter-col" style="margin-right:0;" for="pref-orderby">Brand</label>
                        <select id="br" class="form-control">
                            <option value="brands">Brand 1</option>
                        </select>
                        <label class="filter-col" style="margin-right:0;" for="pref-orderby">Campaign</label>
                        <select id="camp" class="form-control">
                            <option values="camps">Campaign 1</option>
                        </select>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default filter-col">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-record"></span> Submit
                        </button>  
                    </div> <!-- form group [order by] -->
                </div>
```

Comment: Post your ajax code and the `json` op you get .

Comment: `prepStmt = con.prepareStatement(dbquery.get_trademark);
          rs=prepStmt.executeQuery();
          while(rs.next())
            {
            json.put(rs.getString(1),rs.getString(2));
            System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
            System.out.println(rs.getString(2));
            }
        
         
        String responsetojsp=json.toString(); 
        System.out.println(responsetojsp);
        response.setContentType("application/json");
        response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        response.getWriter().write(responsetojsp);' `this is how i return from my jsp

Comment: the JSON output that i get is _ {"11":"Trademark 2","6":"Trademark 1"}_

Comment: Have you tried the adding the `datatype` in the ajax code ?

Comment: the ajax call is  ` $.get('../Paid_deep_dive',{type:"bodyload",s_date:$start_date,e_date:$end_date},function(responseTM)`

Comment: please edit your question with appropriate code , dont post the code as comments

Comment: @San Krish sorry i have edited my question now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parse the response text before save it into a variable . Then pass the variable to `$.each` .

```
 var jsonObject = JQuery.parseJSON(responseTM);
$.each(jsonObject , function(key, value) {  

$('<option>').val(key).text(value).appendTo($select); 

});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are making the ajax call to get the `json` response , make sure you explicitly specify the `dataType`.

```
dataType: 'json'
```

I guess you are parsing the `String` instead of `Object` .Because by default the dataType is`text`